# Trying to Draw a 24bit image in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, illegalargumentexception

I have an image that where each pixel is 4 byte i.e. red mask is 0xFF0000 green is 0xFF00 and blue 0xFF. I read in the image and pass it to a function as function(byte imgBuff,int w,int h)
I then have

```
  void fun(byte imgBuff,int w,int h)
  {
      Graphics g;
      BufferedImage img;
      DataBuffer dBuffer = new DataBufferByte(imgBuff, w * h);
      WritableRaster wr = Raster.createPackedRaster(dBuffer,w,h,24,null);
      DirectColorModel dcm = new DirectColorModel(24,0xFF0000,0xFF00,0xFF);
      img = new BufferedImage(dcm,wr,false,null);
      g = getGraphics();
      g.drawImage(img,x,y,w,h,null);
  }
```

But when I run I get

> Exception in thread "Thread-23" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Raster sun.awt.image.SunWritableRaster@1d82ed7 is incompatible with
>   ColorModel DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=0

How do I go from bytebuffer via `PackedRaster` to Buffered Image for 24bit over four bytes

Comment: 4 bytes is a 32-bit image.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to convert a stream of byte sample data into a `BufferedImage`.

To clarify a few things a 4-byte/pixel image is a 32-bit/pixel image (as 4 * 8 is 32), however the actual color components **may** only span 24-bits (3 bytes) as one 8-bit component is left for Alpha (transparency). Given this fact, is it perfectly normal to have a 24-bit image with 8-bits per color channel and no alpha channel (where the image would then be a 3-byte/pixel image).

The reason you are getting the incompatibility exception is that you are using the wrong method to create your WritableRaster.

Given that your input data is in the form of a byte array and that you are trying to create a image where each byte stores not the whole pixel but a **sample of a pixel** the method `createPackedRaster()` is immediately deemed unsuitable as the method treats every data element (i.e. every byte) as its own pixel which definitely isn't what you're trying to accomplish here.

To determine which of the "create" methods you need to use, you need to determine the format of the incoming data.

The three main types of sample encoding is displayed below:

[image: Image Sample Encoding Demonstration]

*Image Source [amor.cms.hu-berlin.de](http://amor.cms.hu-berlin.de/~janzandr/EnMAP-Box_1_4/documentation/lib/hubAPI/help/idldoc/hub/IO/Img/_image-data-input-output.html)*

They are the Band Sequential Format (bsq), Band Interleaved by Pixel Format (bip) and Band Interleaved by Line Format (bil). The image demonstrates how a 3 by 3 sample image may be encoded. For the sake of simplicity we will only consider the latter two (BIP and BIL) as BSQ is rarely used (*as far as I know*).

If the image data coming through is in the format of BIP, also simply know as pixel interleaved, you will need to use the `createInterleavedRaster()` method to read the input data. As the documentation states:

> Creates a Raster based on a PixelInterleavedSampleModel with the specified data type.

Another factor we need to determine is that if the byte data coming through contains alpha, in essence whether the image data is like this (assuming BIP):

> R G B R G B ....

or

> R G B A R G B A ....

Since there are many overloaded methods taking different parameters we shall use the one that takes a dataType, the width, the height, the bands and a location.

For the dataType we shall use the constant `DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE` since we are inputting a byte array.

The width and height are supplied by our method parameters, nothing funky here.

The bands corresponds to how many distinct bands of data are there. If your input stream doesn't contain alpha you will have three distinct bands (red, green and blue). If your input data contains alpha your image will have four bands (red, green, blue and alpha).

The statement will look like the following:

```
//Replace '4' with '3' if your image doesn't have alpha
WritableRaster wr = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, w, h, 4, null);
```

---

Next part to worry about is the ColorModel. Since we are no longer using `createPackedRaster()` method we need to change the type of our ColorModel as well to `ComponentColorModel`. As this is getting a bit long, I will just show you what I did (please do read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ComponentColorModel.html) yourself though).

As follows:

```
ColorSpace sRGB = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);

//Change the first 'true' to 'false' if you don't have alpha.
ComponentColorModel ccm = new ComponentColorModel(sRGB, true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
```

Now, assembling it all together:

```
void fun(byte[] imgBuff,int w,int h) throws IOException{
    WritableRaster wr = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, w, h, 4, null);

    wr.setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, imgBuff);

    ColorSpace sRGB = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);

    ComponentColorModel ccm = new ComponentColorModel(sRGB, true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(ccm, wr, false, null);
}
```

You will note I added a line `wr.setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, imgBuff)`. This line effectively does the actual data population into the WritableRaster using the byte array directly (no need to create a DataBufferByte object).

I mentioned earlier I would talk about both BIP and BIL. Changing the method above from BIP to BIL should as simple as swapping the `createInterleavedRaster()` method to `createBandedRaster()` and it *should* (I may be wrong here) work just the same.

Comment: Okay I nearly have this working but not able to sort the Colour side of things. I have BandedRaster and the order of the bytes are one byte Alpha, followed by one byte Red, followed by one byte Green, followed by one byte Blue. But the colour is not coming out correct for example if my data has 0x00FFFFFF then it should be white where as its coming out turquouse

Comment: Code is as follows
WritableRaster wr = Raster.createBandedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE,w,h,4,null);
wr.setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, imgBuff);
ColorSpace sRGB = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);

ComponentColorModel ccm = new ComponentColorModel(sRGB, true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
img = new BufferedImage(ccm,wr,false,null);

Comment: @user2873619 Just to point out, if your data comes in as `A R G B` then its pixel interleaved not BIL (which would appear as `A A R R G G B B...` (for a 2 pixel wide image). Is it absolutely necessary to use `WritableRaster`s? I personally stick to simple for loops for image manipulation. Another thing to point out, input data 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF will not be white because alpha is 0 (fully transparent). The reason why you see some odd colour is that the `sRGB` colorspace defines data to be in format `RGBA`. So your alpha is being mapped to your red, red to green and so on.

Comment: Thanks - Not trying tp manipulate image, just plot it on the screen. i.e. Have read in image in byte format as I don't know at the time if its 1,4,8,12,16,24 bit and then trying to output it. Have yet to get the 24bit working. The order of the data bytes is A R G B A R G B etc etc. I guess I can change it to R G B A on the input side.

Comment: @user2873619 For `A R G B` input I normally just do [this](http://pastebin.com/2PgNbu4E).

Comment: But that is copying the data from one place to another which I would prefer to avoid if possible. I can change things on the creation side to create the byte buffer as R G B A where A is 0xFF rather than 0x00. I just want the quickest way to display ideally without copying

Comment: @user2873619 If copying data is such a problem then I guess changing to R G B A is a better idea. Just a tip, if your alpha is going to be always opaque (100% alpha), don't bother using an alpha channel. Transfer only R G B. You'll create a 24-bit image instead of a 32-bit one which is also bit better on memory. Instructions on receiving pixel interleaved alpha-less data is in my answer. You can also change the `Transparency.TRANSLUCENT` to `Transparency.OPAQUE` if you desire, shouldn't make much of a difference I think.

Comment: Would I be right in assuming I can create the bufferdimage with
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ARGB);
 img.setRGB(0, 0, w, h, img_buff.TYPE_4BYTE_ARGB, 0, w);

Comment: @user2873619 What is `img_buff`? A byte array? If so, no you cannot do that. `setRGB()` takes a integer array of pixel data in whatever format you specified earlier (btw `TYPE_4BYTE_ARGB` doesn't exist). My code in pastebin specifies `TYPE_INT_ARGB`. If you can make the input data come in R G B A (or just R G B), just use the method I created in my answer.

Comment: @user2873619 **Correction**, just read the documentation. `setRGB()` takes data in format of **ARGB only** (integer packed, sRGB Color Space) and **converts** to whatever format you specified when creating the BufferedImage.